# iPhone 6 charging port for iPhone 6s

Tags: iphone, charging, lightning

I didn't pay close attention and ended up buying a charging port for iPhone 6, but I have an iPhone 6s. On the product image they look kind of similar. Should I just try to install it? Or is this not a good idea?

Sorry if that wasn't clear, I'm talking about the internal lightning connector of the iPhone. Yes, that means that I need to disassamble the iPhone.

This is the charging port for the iPhone 6 I bought:

[image]

The charging port for the iPhone 6s looks kinda similar:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parts are not interchangeable. The mounting brackets, electrical contact pads and the connector at the top right has changed.

[image: differences between the parts]

Chalk this up to learning and get the part needed to your phone.

- The volume of space inside phones is so low that even a slight bend in the part with the electric traces will mean you can’t even close the case physically. You’re missing the bottom right component  and that large flap won’t fit wither as the 6s part is much shorter above the lightning receptacle.
- Worse if you damage the connectors or short the circuitry. Read the battery thermal event pages in the iPhone 14 official repair manual. This piece will be close to your battery so please be safe.

For the [iPhone 14 Repair Manual](https://support.apple.com/en-us/100308), you’re in both the Warning and Caution alert category if you try to use the part you ordered.

> Failure to follow alerts could result in fire, injury, data loss, or damage to the device, parts, or other property.
>
> **Warning** - Instructions for reducing risk of personal injury
> **Caution** - Instructions for reducing risk of data loss or device hardware damage

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I'll order the right part.

Comment: Good luck and mush success on the repair @user1785730